# Index from .map is not expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is the index only the last selected index? See the index sent in on the commented line

```
  <Ol
    width={small && "100%"}
    role="listbox"
    tabindex={stepIndex}
    aria-activedescendant={steps[stepIndex]}
    // aria-labelledby="accordion_form"
  >
    {steps.map((step, index) => (
      <li
        className={getClassName(index)}
        role="option"
        tabindex="0"
        onKeyDown={handleSelectOnKeyDown(index)} // This index is always the same, even though I list out 1, 2 3 on the commented line underneath
        onClick={() => setNextStep(step)}
        id={step}
        aria-selected={steps[stepIndex] === step ? "true" : "false"}
      >
        <span>
          {index + 1}. {schema[step]?.label ?? titleizeWord(step)} // Here it is listed out 1, 2, 3 (with the added +1), so the index is correct here.
        </span>
        {index < stepIndex && <Icon icon={check} left="small" />}
        {small && index === stepIndex && (
          <Icon icon={chevron_down} left="small" />
        )}
      </li>
    ))}
  </Ol>
```

This is the handleSelectOnKeyDown:

```
  const handleSelectOnKeyDown = (index) => ({ keyCode }) => {
    console.log("index", index);
    let nextStep;
    switch (keyCode) {
      case KEYS.ENTER:
      case KEYS.SPACE:
        nextStep = steps[index];
        break;
      case KEYS.UP:
        const upIndex = index > 0 ? index - 1 : 0;
        nextStep = steps[upIndex];
        break;
      case KEYS.DOWN:
        const maxIndex = steps?.length;
        const downIndex = index < (maxIndex - 1) ? index + 1 : maxIndex;
        nextStep = steps[downIndex];
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }

    if (nextStep) {
      setNextStep(nextStep);
    }
  };
```

I would like to get an explanation of what may cause this.

Comment: I want to clarify one thing. My answer currently assumes that you want to get the index of current focused element on the key event (using tab/shift+tab). But after re-reading your question, did you expect that, doing `index+1` in JSX will also increment `index` which you send to your event handler by 1 ? If so that will not happen since you're aren't changing `index` itself but just using it. Let me know if that was the issue and I will delete my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think your implementation needs to change from `onKeyDown` to `onKeyUp`. I am assuming this because when navigating from one `li` item to another, your event will occur on `keydown` but your new focused element will be one index ahead or behind what's logged in console (which happened on keydown).

So in a nutshell, **keydown** will execute when you leave the current element and **keyup** when you arrive at it.

Again when talking about **leaving** and **arriving**, it's using the **Tab/Shift+Tab** navigation keys. For other keys since they don't perform navigation, the `index` value will be consistent with what's focused irresepctive of whether **keydown** was used or **keyup**.

Try the below sandbox :-

[image: Edit keyup]